# Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Missing permission to insert badges

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-xml, android-permissions, android-securityexception

I am new in Android development, I am facing below exception on some of the device after publishing it on play store. It is completly unknown exception for me. This exception force stop/crash my application.

**Complete stacktrace logged:**

```
Exception java.lang.SecurityException: Missing permission to insert badges
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1553)
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:185)
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:137)
android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert (ContentProviderProxy.java:476)
android.content.ContentResolver.insert (ContentResolver.java:1213)
android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage (AsyncQueryHandler.java:96)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:211)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
```

As mentioned above exception dose not contains any part of code that relate to my application, and also I am not found any satisfactory solution for above issue.

**EDIT:** 
I am using an external library(SDK) for push notification, after adding that my App start showing 11 new permission on play store 'Required permission' section when I am going to update my app

**Some of those permissions are:**

```
    com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS
    com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT
    com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE
    com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS
    com.huawei.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
    com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ
    com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE
    com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE
    com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDE_INSERT_BADGE
```

I am not added these permission in my own manifest file, So that I modified my **'AndroidManifest'** file by adding following line of code into application tag:

```
<application
     <--some code-->
    tools:replace="android:icon, android:allowBackup"
    >
```

and use a .jar file of SDK instead of compile it like

compile 'com.abc.xyz:3.+@aar' //suggested for android studio in (build.gradle)

After applying above process those permission are removed and I upload my Application.

Only These thing I have performed into my new version of app. I also looked that library project recentally and it contains a folder **'shortcutbadger'** that contains some sub-folder and .class file internally

**Is due to above changes I am start receiving that exception ? please explain/help!**

Comment: There should be some code in your app where App icons are updated with badges. Normally badges are updated through Intents. So try to figure out where you do that & post the code. Also different Phone vendors require different Intents to make this work.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/110)

Comment: @sJy added complete details and part of code I applied, after which start facing above exception

Comment: Which is the "external library" you used??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said, you can change a gradle dependency with a Jar of the same SDK. But when using Jar, you should make sure all the permissions are added appropriately in manifest in order to make the SDK work properly.

The OneSignal SDK which you have used recommends gradle dependency for Android Studio & Jar file with additional permissions in Manifest for Eclipse. Since you replaced gradle with Jar in Studio, make sure you have the following permissions added to manifest file.

```
<permission android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<!-- START: ShortcutBadger -->
<!-- Samsung -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"/>

<!-- HTC -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"/>

<!-- Sony -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE"/>

<!-- Apex -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"/>

<!-- Solid -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"/>

<!-- Huawei -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<!-- End: ShortcutBadger -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Are the devices Samsung? Samsung and some other brands have launchers where you can add badges to app icons, perhaps your code or code from a library is trying to use it?

You need to add the correct permission for it to your App Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "ShortcutBadger" Android Library then you need to follow this instruction

**`API >= 23`** now require special permission. Try to make it through **`onRequestPermissionsResult`**

[also check this url](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/110)